# Uniform convergence of sequence of functions with infinite roots to a limit with finite roots

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ defined over $[0,1]$ such that, for all $n$, the set:

$$A_n = \{x\in [0,1] : f_n(x) = 0\}$$

is infinite in cardinality.  Can $(f_n)$ uniformly converge to some continuous limit $f$ which only has finitely many zeroes?  What if $f$ only has finitely many *crossings*, and no other zeroes, and for each $f_n$ there are infinitely many *crossings* (and no other zeroes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question. For $n>2$ let
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1/2-1/n-x}{1/2-1/n} &0\le x\le1/2-1/n\\
0 & 1/2-1/n<x<1/2+1/n\\
\dfrac{x-1/2-1/n}{1/2-1/n} & 1/2+1/n\le x\le1\end{cases}
$$
Then $\{x\in[0,1]:f_n(x)=0\}=[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n]$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $|2\,x-1|$.

For the second, you can use the same type of function changing its value on the interval $[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n]$ to
$$
\frac1n\,(1/2-1/n-x)(x-1/2-1/n)\sin\frac{1}{(1/2-1/n-x)(x-1/2-1/n)}.
$$

Comment: Great examples, were very helpful.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For $n=3,4,\dots,$ let $g_n$ be the function whose graph consists of the three line segments connecting $(0,0),(1/n,0),(2/n,1),(1,1).$ Define $f_n(x) = xg_n(x).$ Then $f_n(x) \to x$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ Note each $f_n$ has uncountably many zeros, while $f(x)=x$ has only one zero.

I assume by "crossing" you mean a change of sign. Here you could let $f_n(x) = (1/n)x\sin(1/x).$ Each $f_n$ has infinitely many crossings, while the $f_n$'s converge uniformly to $0,$ which has no crossings.